# Jquery closest content to load HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load a HTML text on a nearest element with a class name `content` using query closest, but could not get it to appear, since i am displaying the `html` content inside a `php` loop i believe using the `closest()` function is the best way to do this. but looks like i am missing something.

My HTML

```
<ul  class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li class="collection-items">
      <a class="collapsible-header" style="color:black;"><i class="material-icons">folder_open</i>TOM CAT</a>
      <div class="collapsible-body">

      <span class="content">
              <!--This is where the hello should be-->
        </span>

        </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

My jquery

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {



     $('.collapsible-header').on('click', function(e) {

          console.log('this is click');

            var co = $(this).closest(".collapsible-body").find("span.content").html("Hello!");


      });



});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible-header').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('this is click');
    var co = $(this).closest(".collection-items").find("span.content").html("Hello!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li class="collection-items">
    <a class="collapsible-header" style="color:black;"><i class="material-icons">folder_open</i>TOM CAT</a>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <span class="content">
              <!--This is where the hello should be-->
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: or use next css selector - $('~ .collapsible-body .content', this).html("Hello!");

Comment: Thank that worked i was really lost with that elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `closest()` method searches up in the tree to find the `.collapsible-body`. But in the code, the `.collapsible-body` is below the `.collapsible-header` that is clicked. Therefore the function displays nothing.

Comment: Good point, but your answer should provide a code solution, this looks more like a comment.

Comment: `.next()` can be used i.e.  `var co = $(this).next(".collection-items").find("span.content").html("Hello!");`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing small mistake here:-

Check below lines:-

```
1) $(this).next(".collapsible-body").find("span.content").html("Hello!");
```

The next() method returns the next sibling element of the selected element.

```
2) $(this).closest(".collection-items").find("span.content").html("Hello!");
```

closest() looks at the current element and its parents only

Hope this will clear you the concept between both.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to do this but keep in mind jquery is DOM heavy and affect the performance if not used wisely. I would do this the following way,

```
$(function() {
  $('.collapsible-header').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next().find("span.content").html("Hello!");
  });
});
```

The above code will not loop through all the elements closest to it but jump to the next element which is pretty fast to spot!